# Excel: determine the current display area

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there a way to determine the Excel's current display area? This is in full screen mode. What I'm after is a range, something like `K2:AA20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need VBA:

```
Sub get_visibble_range()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
Debug.Print (r.Address)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. The reply came surprisingly quick.

Comment: @joehua - note that this includes partially visible rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The sub above is what I wanted.